# Object Recognition Programmatically?

Tags: object-detection

Inspired by a recent Kickstarter campaign: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/dominikmazur/camfind-a-mobile-visual-search-app?ref=category

The app uses the mobile camera to take a picture and identify virtually any object. Snapping a photo of a movie poster will recognize the movie and pull up results on the web for you about it, taking a picture of a product will show you websites that product is available for sale on.

My question is, is this realistic? I find it very intriguing, but it object detection really that simple? I'm interested in some feedback regarding resources to help someone get started in learning about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computer vision and [Pattern Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition) is not easy at all. It's an entire field related to Artificial Intelligence. It is, however, relatively straightforward to understand at a high level though. There is ***NO WAY*** they are doing this all on the client. The phones just aren't fast enough, and do not have even *close* to enough storage space.

What they are most likely doing is sending the image to their servers, then use some kind of nearest neighbour approximation on the image, and run the result through a decision tree look-up in a *massive* database on images which all have some hash. This will give a close match to an image they have (assuming they have ***A LOT*** of images in there database), even if only part of the image matches. Then, using the hash, they look up some other information about that image to send to the device.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: That does help a lot. Confirms my disbelief in that project and also provides some keywords that i can go and look up to help start satisfying my "how could this be done" questions. I'll look into comparing images server side using nearest neighbour approximation. Thank you.